# Opening a new window on successful ajax login

Tags: php, javascript, html

In the following code, on successful login, I am trying to open admin.htm. the content is loaded into the same page using AJAX, how can I instead open it in a new window but retain any error messages in the original window in case of error?

**login.htm**

```
 <form> 
    Username:<input type="text" name= "username" size="15" /> 
    Password:<input type="password" name= "passwrd" size="15" />
    <input name="submit" type = "button" onClick = "getdata('login.php','display',username.value,passwrd.value)"  value = "Login"  /> 
    </form>    

    <div id="display"></div>
```

**login.js**

```
function getdata(dataSource, divID, usrname, pwd) {
    if (xhr) {
        var obj = document.getElementById(divID);
        var requestbody = "username=" + encodeURIComponent(usrname) + "&password=" + encodeURIComponent(pwd);
        xhr.open("POST", dataSource, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                obj.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            }
        }
        xhr.send(requestbody);
    }
}
```

Comment: edited your tags. PHP has nothing to do with windows. it's server-side language

Comment: Your indentation is crying -- nay, _screaming_ -- out for some love and attention. Fancy taking a crack at it?

Comment: @Col: I think `php` is what wants removing from the question. Login.php is a complete red herring, and the OP doesn't appear to understand that HTML and Javascript and PHP are distinct.

Comment: @jisa: Where is the code where you mention _anything_ about a new window? And you need to stop the original form submission from continuing. This question is better suited to a chatroom.

Comment: Why are you so unfriendly to noobs?

Comment: @Tom it turns out is IS possibly about PHP too. We just did not have enough information to judge that until OP commented on my answer.

Comment: @mplugjan: Not bothering to format your code when presenting it to the public for help has nothing to do with being a language newcomer; it's merely laziness/messiness. I feel no obligation at all to sugar-coat that. I've seen some pretty great questions from people who have barely even touched the language before. And if you think that this is me being "unfriendly" then you must not know me that well ;) Fact is, this is not a question about a programming language -- it is a request for debugging help and that is not what SO is for. i.e. it is _too localised_.

Comment: window.open() is pretty much your option.

Comment: @Tom - granted I did not look at this question before it may have been reformatted, however the question "How to I change an Ajax load from php into a new window" is not THAT localised. And the solution to the OPs problem did involve the server process. So my stance is instead of telling newcomers off, try to make them ask better questions without your "Go away and ask this somewhere far away from our elitist forum" which I found very unfriendly.

Comment: @mplugjan: I never said anything like that at all. Why do you people always jump to the conclusion that it's an elitist stance? It's not. Iterative debugging is simply suited better to a real-time conversation than a Q&A format, _that's all_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the form is using AJAX on purpose to display the result on the page you are on...

To open the result in a new page, remove the onclick and the script and give a target:

```
<form action="login.php" target="_blank" method="post"> 
Username:<input type="text" name= "username" size="15" /> 
Password:<input type="password" name= "passwrd" size="15" />
<input type="submit" value = "Login"  /> 
</form>
```

If all you want is to NOT see the form after submit, wrap the form in the display div:

```
<div id="display">
  <form>.....
  </form>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE:**

```
to get the error message into the page, do 

if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
  var text = xhr.responseText;
  if (text.indexOf("You must") == 0) obj.innerHTML = text;
  else window.open(text,"_blank")
}

<?php
$usernam = $_POST["username"];
$pwd = $_POST["password"];
if (empty($usernam) || empty($pwd)) {
    echo "You must enter both username and password to login.";
} else {
    echo 'admin.htm';
}
?>
```

Comment: but it will show message( in case if any field is empty) and admin.htm in new window but i need to show error message under the form but admin.htm in new window